# SSL "unable to get local issuer certificate" : "full chain" vs "root"?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, curl, lets-encrypt

**Summary**

In summary I have some certificate related files and some certificate related instructions but I'm not sure which files are which !

**Background**

I've just installed a certificate from Lets Encrypt by using [acme.sh](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh)

The output from that process looks like this :

```
[Sat Aug 18 02:50:24 UTC 2018] Your cert is in  /home/ubuntu/.acme.sh/www.foobar.xyz/www.foobar.xyz.cer
[Sat Aug 18 02:50:24 UTC 2018] Your cert key is in  /home/ubuntu/.acme.sh/www.foobar.xyz/www.foobar.xyz.key
[Sat Aug 18 02:50:24 UTC 2018] The intermediate CA cert is in  /home/ubuntu/.acme.sh/www.foobar.xyz/ca.cer
[Sat Aug 18 02:50:24 UTC 2018] And the full chain certs is there:  /home/ubuntu/.acme.sh/www.foobar.xyz/fullchain.cer
```

So after configuring Nginx this is all works when requests are made to https://www.foobar.xyz through a conventional browser.

**Problem**

But when I make the same request via Curl I get :

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

So it seems there are two ways to fix this.

- tell Curl to ignore the issue or provide curl with a client side list of certificating authorities.
- alter the certificate on the server

**Question**

I want the second option, the change on the server, and [this page gives instructions](https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/203427642-How-to-install-a-SSL-certificate-on-a-NGINX-server) on how to do it specifically ...

> 2) If you received the intermediate certificates in one bundle file or
>   downloaded the certificate files in your account with us, you can use
>   this command:
>
> cat example_com.crt bundle.crt >> ssl-bundle.crt
>
> Place the concatenated file into the directory with SSL certificates
>   on your Nginx server.

The problem I have is that I'm not sure which of the files produced by running acme.sh correspond to the example_com.crt and the bundle.crt ?

I think bundle.crt corresponds to www.foobar.xyz.cer ?

But I'm not sure what example_com.crt corresponds to ?

Comment: Aside: the names of files are irrelevant, only the content counts. You should name the files in such a way that they are clear to you what they contain.

Answer (score 1):

The bundle is `fullchain.cer`. It contains `ca.cer` and `www.foobar.xyz.cer`.